# Three.js TrackballControls.js rotating in z & x axis only

Tags: javascript, three.js

I,m trying to set TracballControls in threejs to move only in two axles, only pan and tilt, without roll. Is there any possibilities to make it?
My code: http://360.art.pl/experimental/2/
Mouse move should behave like this: http://360.art.pl/experimental/1/

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you: (solved my problem)

look in your TrackballControl.js-file and change the line 148

from:

```
_this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
```

to:

```
_this.object.up.applyQuaternion( new THREE.Vector4(0,0,0,1) );
```

//Update
Only work with older versions

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. The cube spins on the same 3 axis, but now there appears to be a gimbal lock issue.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is very old, but as it's still the main result in google I'll describe how I made this work.

To prevent roll (lock the z axis), you can prevent rotateCamera() from making changes to the camera's Up vector.

Comment out the line (~line 200)

```
_this.object.up.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
```

If you like you can lock the camera's rotation vector as well, add either

```
_this.object.rotation.z = 0;
```

or

```
_this.object.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
```

to the end of the function. However in practice I found this doesn't make much difference as most of the rotation is caused by movement of the camera relative to it's lookAt target (_this.target in the trackballControls.js file).

Answer (score 0):

i just changed the variable

```
this.noPan
```

on line 26 to false.
Uncommented

```
_this.object.up.applyQuaternion( quaternion );
```

And increased the

```
this.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.2;
```

to 0.8.